# Push variables into array to draw shape but nothing appears

Tags: javascript, arrays, html5-canvas, draw

I've created a shape, and I've pushed the variables of the object into an array called allShapes, i then tried executing the function, but nothing appears seems to appear. I know the drawing works so I'm assuming I'm missing something?
Here's all of my code so far.
(PS. to draw the shape, I'm using functions "forward" and "turn" to determine the length and directions of the lines in the shape)

function for drawing :shape1
name of variable for array :allShapes
function to push variables of shape1 into array : addObject

```js
var canvas;
var ctx;
var w = 1000;
var h = 600;

var allShapes = [];

setUpCanvas();

for (var i = 0; i < allShapes.length; i++) {
  shape1(allShapes[i]);
}

function addObject(a) {
  a.push({
    "x": w / 2,
    "y": h / 2,
    "w": 50,
    "h": 30,
    "d": 5,
    "angle": 0,
    "changle": 15,
    "c": 180,
  })
}

function shape1(o) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(o.x, o.y);
  for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    turn(o, 60);
    forward(o, 50 + i * 5);
    ctx.lineTo(o.x, o.y);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

function turn(o, angle) {
  if (angle != undefined) {
    o.changle = angle;
  };
  o.angle += o.changle;
}

function forward(o, d) {
  var changeX;
  var changeY;
  var oneDegree = Math.PI / 180;
  if (d != undefined) {
    o.d = d;
  };
  changeX = o.d * Math.cos(o.angle * oneDegree);
  changeY = o.d * Math.sin(o.angle * oneDegree);
  o.x += changeX;
  o.y += changeY;
}

//// GENERAL STUFF 

function randn(r) {
  var result = Math.random() * r - r / 2;
  return result
}

function randi(r) {
  var result = Math.floor(Math.random() * r);
  return result
}

function rand(r) {
  return Math.random() * r
}

function setUpCanvas() {
  canvas = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = w;
  canvas.height = h;
  canvas.style.border = "5px solid orange";
}

console.log("Assignment 3");
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="myCanvas">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: the only `push` in your code is in function `addObject` ... which is never called

Comment: One may choose to use snippets (edit-question and there's a button like this: **`<>`**) to provide a quicker way to execute the code within stackoverflow question itself. This question has been edited to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this helps with finding a solution. The shape is now rendered.

```js
let canvas, ctx;
const w = 400, h = 250; // reduced dimensions to fit demo-window
// const w = 1000, h = 600; 

const allShapes = [];

setUpCanvas();

for (var i = 0; i < allShapes.length; i++) {
  shape1(allShapes[i]);
};

function addObject(a) {
  a.push({
    "x": w / 2,
    "y": h / 2,
    "w": 50,
    "h": 30,
    "d": 5,
    "angle": 0,
    "changle": 15,
    "c": 180,
  })
}

function shape1(o) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(o.x, o.y);
  for (let i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    turn(o, 60);
    forward(o, 50 + i * 5);
    ctx.lineTo(o.x, o.y);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

function turn(o, angle) {
  if (angle != undefined) {
    o.changle = angle;
  };
  o.angle += o.changle;
}

function forward(o, d) {
  let changeX, changeY, oneDegree = Math.PI / 180;
  if (d != undefined) {
    o.d = d;
  };
  changeX = o.d * Math.cos(o.angle * oneDegree);
  changeY = o.d * Math.sin(o.angle * oneDegree);
  o.x += changeX;
  o.y += changeY;
}

//// GENERAL STUFF 

function randn(r) { return Math.random() * r - r / 2; };

function randi(r) { return Math.floor(Math.random() * r); };

function rand(r) { return Math.random() * r; };

function setUpCanvas() {
  canvas = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = w;
  canvas.height = h;
  canvas.style.border = "5px solid orange";
  // invoked the "addObject" function with empty "allShapes" array
  addObject(allShapes);
}

console.log("Assignment 3");
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="myCanvas">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

**NOTES**

1. One line (a call to the `"addObject"` method) has been added.
2. Where possible, preference is to use `let` and `const` (in lieu of `var`)